# Power BI Live Connection to SSAS - XNPV with separate data and date tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried to write a measure to calculate the XNPV of transactions from the data table, but it's giving me 2 problems:

1. It's not calculating correctly, just spitting out the same raw data as the data table, and
2. it won't even resolve if there's any blanks for any dates on the data table.

Here's my measure:

```
MyPV = 
XNPV(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES('Dates'[Date]),
        "Transactions", 'TransData1'[Values]
    ),
    [Transactions],
    Dates[Date],
    1.0775
)
```

The SSAS environment is already configured to have separate date and data tables, but I want to avoid reinventing the XNPV wheel if possible, since that'll likely introduce lag.

I tested my measure on a few different transaction data sources, but it caused any visuals to error unless there were no blank values for the time period filtered.

Comment: Is `'TransData1'[Values]` a Measure or Column?

Comment: Hi Sam, 'TransData1'[Values] is a measure. I've never questioned it before, but there are several 'TransDataX' tables where X ranges from 2 to 9, each with it's own Values column. Only the 'TransData1' table has the [Values] measure, but it's the only one that gives me the correct output. Parallelized data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` which won't return any blank values.

```
MyPV A = 
  XNPV(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      'Dates'[Date],
      "Transactions", MIN('TransData1'[Values]) // or 'TransData1'[Values] if measure
    ),
    [Transactions],
    [Date],
    1.0775
  )
```

Or filter out blanks:

```
MyPV B = 
  XNPV(
    FILTER(
      ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES('Dates'[Date]),
        "Transactions", 'TransData1'[Values]
      ), 
      NOT ISBLANK([Transactions])
    ),
    [Transactions],
    [Date],
    1.0775
  )
```

Comment: SUMMARIZECOLUMNS isn't supported in measures (only works when visual isn't grouping by any column, as group by is performed by another SUMMARIZECOLUMNS, that measure will work in a card) and calculated columns

Comment: Fair point, alternative posted for that scenario.

Comment: Alternative worked! Thank you both so much for your help!